# Getting Geolocation after every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript

I had a query that as I am working on a small map (OSM) and I want that the cars which would run on the network layer created via JOSM with defined speed should return their GPS coordinates after every 30 seconds, if i wanted to change the path of the car midway, Is it possible with MATSim or is there other software for it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function success(position) {
    //retrieve lat and long
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude
}

function error(){
    //error handling
}

setInterval(function(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval

```
setInterval(() => {
    // foo();
}, 30000)
```

Comment: I think retriving geolocation is an async operation so this will desynchronize